# In MVC, pass complex query and view model to session?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, pagination

I have a view model:

```
 public class UserCollectionView
    {
        public CardCollection CardCollections { get; set; }
        public Card Cards { get; set; }    
    }
```

I have a List View Controller:

```
public ActionResult ViewCollection(int? page)
        {
            var userid = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            int pageSize = 5;                
            ViewBag.OnePageOfCards = pageNumber;
            if (Session["CardCollection"] != null)
            {    
             var paging = Session["CardCollection"].ToString.();
             return View(paging.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));    
            }                                  
            var viewModel = from c in db.Cards
                            join j in db.CardCollections on c.CardID equals j.CardID
                            where (j.NumberofCopies > 0) && (j.UserID == userid)
                            orderby c.Title
                            select new UserCollectionView { Cards = c, CardCollections = j };

            Session["CardCollection"] = viewModel;
            return View(viewModel.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

I am trying to use the PagedList to add paging to the results. I have been able to do this when I am not using a query that returns data from 2 databases in a single view. [As shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014212/how-to-use-pagedlist-on-search-results-page-in-mvc)

My end result looks something like this:

```
     Cards.SeveralColumns   CardCollections.ColumnA   CardCollections.ColumnB 
Row 1 Data from Cards Table  A from CardCollections    B from CardCollections
Row 2 Data from Cards Table  A from CardCollections    B from CardCollections
Row 3 Data from Cards Table  A from CardCollections    B from CardCollections
```

And so on... I get an error 
`The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`
I have tried variations of SQL statements but can't get it to fit with my view model. In SQL Management Studio this brings back the correct results
`Select * from Cards Inner Join CardCollections On Cards.CardID = CardCollections.CardID where CardCollections.UserID = 1 and CardCollections.NumberofCopies > 0;`

I need a way to pass the query in session so the paging will operate correctly. Any advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: Does this error occur in the controller or when rendering the view?

Comment: It happens when I select the 2nd page after the view is initially rendered. The error occurs in the controller. It passes a lot of stuff in the CardCollection Session, but the Results view states `The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't need to pass the query at all. If I let it run through it works fine without the session. I am not really sure why this works but my search query has to be passed. Maybe it is because I am using a viewmodel to perform the query. I will experiment and post if I find anything. Currently the working code is:

```
public ActionResult ViewCollection(int? page)
        {
            var userid = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            int pageSize = 5;

            ViewBag.OnePageOfCards = pageNumber;
            ViewBag.Rarity_ID = new SelectList(db.Rarities, "RarityID", "Title");
            ViewBag.MainType_ID = new SelectList(db.MainTypes, "MainTypeID", "Title");
            ViewBag.CardSet_ID = new SelectList(db.CardSets, "CardSetID", "Title");
            ViewBag.SubType_ID = new SelectList(db.SubTypes, "SubTypeID", "Title");
            var viewModel = from c in db.Cards
                            join j in db.CardCollections on c.CardID equals j.CardID
                            where (j.NumberofCopies > 0) && (j.UserID == userid)
                            orderby c.Title
                            select new UserCollectionView { Cards = c, CardCollections = j };
            return View(viewModel.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Comment: You're simply re-fetching the data every time the action is called. ToPagedList is, most likely, executing the query (so now you have live data and not an `IQueryable`), which is then passed off (as a collection) to your view model, assembled.

Comment: My search uses ToPagedList  `var CardList = db.Cards.SqlQuery(SQLstatement).ToList();` `return View(CardList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));` But I have to pass the query in session or it crashes because it tries to rerun the entire search that builds the query without any values.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is, you can't. The model needs to be a snapshot of the content and therefore you can't pass an open query across the boundary (either as a hand-off to a session or to the client directly).

What you're seeing is the disposal of the context beyond it's initial use (where you assemble `var viewmodel`).

With that said, you can cache the results (to save overhead) if querying the data is an expensive operation. Basically, you'd store the entire collection (or at least a large subset of the collection) in the session/memorycache (which can then be manipulated into a paged list). Something to the effect of:

```
public ActionResult ViewCollection(int? page)
{
  var userId = (int) WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
  var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
  var pageSize = 5;

  ViewBag.OnePageOfCards = pageNumber;

  var cacheKey = String.Format("ViewCollection[{0}]", userId);
  var entities = GetOrCreateCacheItem<IEnumerable<UserCollectionView>>(cacheKey, () => {
    var query = (from c in db.Cards
                 join j in db.CardCollections on c.CardID equals j.CardID
                 where (j.NumberofCopies > 0) && (j.UserID == userid)
                 orderby c.Title
                 select new UserCollectionView { Cards = c, CardCollections = j }
                )
                .ToList(); // Force fetch from Db so we can cache
  });

  return View(entities.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}

// To give an example of a cache provider; Feel free to change this,
// abstract it out, etc.
private T GetOrCreateCacheItem<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getItem)
{
  T cacheItem = MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as T;
  if (cacheItem == null)
  {
    cacheItem = getItem();
    var cacheExpiry = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
    MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, cacheItem, cacheExpiry);
  }
  return cacheItem;
}
```